# How to grep "\n" in file

Tags: linux, grep

Sample file : abc.ksh

```bash
echo "This is a sample file." >> mno.txt
echo "\nThis line has new line char." >> mno.txt
```

I want

```bash
echo "\nThis line has new line char." >> mno.txt
```

as output.

Comment: Linebreak determines the end of line; there can't be a linebreak in the middle of the line.

Comment: Escape the backslash: `grep '\\n' abc.ksh` - you're welcome :-)

Comment: `grep -F '\n' abc.ksh` will also work, `-F` tells grep to look for the pattern as a fixed string.

Comment: fgrep takes only fixed patterns: `fgrep \n mno.txt`

Comment: That echo command is ambiguous. In some shells it writes two characters, a backsplash and then a `n`; in others it writes an actual newline.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `-F` to match fixed strings:

```bash
$ grep -F "\n" file
echo "\nThis line has new line char." >> mno.txt
```

From `man grep`:

> **-F, --fixed-strings**
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
> any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: @Crusader I need more context

Comment: -zoP keys helps

Comment: @Crusader still don't know what you mean, try to elaborate a bit

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is using REGEX:

```bash
grep "$" filename  # this will match all lines ending with "\n" (often all lines)
grep "PATTERN$"    # this will match all lines ending with "PATTERN\n"
```

In REGEX language, `$` means EOL (end of line), so it will often match `"\n"` (cause is very common as the end of line).

WARNING: be careful to use versions of `grep` that support REGEX!.

Answer (score 3):

Simply escape the backslash with another backslash and put the regex in single quotes so the shell does pass it to grep without handling the backslashes itself:

```bash
grep '\\n' abc.ksh
```

Comment: @Samha' Which is your shell and grep version? it works for me in ubuntu fine

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression pattern search

```bash
grep -P '\n' mno.txt
```

Comment: or another option `grep $'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

`grep -zoP '[^\n]*\n[^\n]*' file`

- -z - change all \n to zero byte
- -o - show only diff (because whole file is one line for grep now)
- -P - perl regexp

find \n and line before and after

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this by escaping the backslash with another backslash:

```bash
grep '\\n' xyz.ksh
```