# How to use grep to find string that contain "\n" char?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to use the powerful `grep` to find those strings that contain the following sentence in the `MATLAB` source files in the directory.

```
    fprintf('Error: invalid indexes!\n');
```

I've tried the following command, but it shows errors.

```
    grep -rl "fprintf(\'Error: invalid indexes!\\n\');" ./
```

I've tried the solutions presented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659657/how-to-grep-n-in-file), but it seems to not work.

Could you please give some advice?

In addition, after find those matched strings, I want to replace them into the following sentence:

```
    if(length(invalid_idx)>0) fprintf('Error: invalid indexes!\n'); end
```

I know we could use the following command:

```
    grep -rl "need_to_replaced_strings" ./ | xargs sed -i 's/need_to_replaced_strings/replaced_strings/g'
```

I'm not sure if the `replaced_strings` in the command above should have some special considerations.

The errors is as follows:
[image]

Comment: `but it shows errors` Please, post those error messages

Comment: Have you tried the `-F` option of grep?

Comment: @Jdamian, thanks! I've updated the post with the error information, please kindly check it.

Comment: I see you have not tried my answer.

Comment: @Jdamian, thank you! I've tried your answer, but it seems to something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ grep -Erl 'fprintf\('\''Error: invalid indexes!\\n'\''\);' ./

fprintf('Error: invalid indexes!\n');
```

use `-E` option and escape the inner single quotes`'\''` outside the single-quoted string.

Or, if escape the single quotes by `'"'"'` as below:

```
$ grep -Erl 'fprintf\('"'"'Error: invalid indexes!\\n'"'"'\);' ./
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk way with the substitution i think you want

```
awk -vS="'" '{sub("fprintf\\("S"Error: invalid indexes!\\\\n"S"\\);","?",$0)}1' file
```

Example

#### Input

```
dsfdsf
sdfds
fprintf('Error: invalid indexes!\n');
sdf
dsf
sdf
```

#### Ouput

```
dsfdsf
sdfds
?
sdf
dsf
sdf
```

Comment: Thank you for kindly providing the candidate solution! I've replaced those strings one by one by hand....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -rlF "fprintf('Error: invalid indexes"'!\n'"');" ./
```