# grep behavior with "\n" in regex

Tags: grep

Can somebody explain this behavior?

I'm matching a string with pattern in 3 different cases.

**Case 1:** In Java

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(b8|a8|8d){1,1}$"); #A dummy pattern
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("a8\n");  #A dummy string
boolean result = matcher.matches();

#result is false, which is expected
```

**Case 2:** In JavaScript

```
var str = "a8\n";
var patt = /^(b8|a8|8d){1,1}$/g;
var result = str.match(patt);

#result prints nothing, again it's expected
```

However

**Case 3:** (grep in bash)

```
[test@th3]$ grep -E '^(b8|a8|8d){1,1}$' <( printf 'a8\n'; )
a8
[test@th3]$

# it matches the 'a8'
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659657/how-to-grep-n-in-file/54542184) question, somebody answered that `$` represents end of line in `REGEX`, hence grep is matching `'\n'` in case 3, but why not in other cases?

Comment: Try `grep -E '^(b8|a8|8d){1,1}$' <( printf 'a8\nb8\nc8\n8d\n'; )` -- grep is splitting its input (on newlines) before testing for matches.

Comment: *"Why people writes `{1,1}` or `{1}` instead of nothing?"* is the new Hilbert's problem.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Could you please explain why have you removed ```regex``` tag? Although the question intent is not directly related to ```regex```, but it is required here.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, yes you are correct, I'm newbie to regex and alternation in this case ```{1,1}``` is not required.

Comment: The issue is not related to regex, only to grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` strips the trailing newline from each line, just as if it were reading from a file. Its input is assumed to be a POSIX text file, not an arbitrary byte stream, so each input line will be newline-free.